# How to take a list as input using the defined ListNode class

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

I was trying to construct a linked list using the above listNode class can someone help me how I can take inputs and construct the linked List in Java
Below is the code:

```
public class ListNode {
    int val;
    ListNode next;
    ListNode() {}
    ListNode(int val) { this.val = val; }
    ListNode(int val, ListNode next) { this.val = val; this.next = next; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you are trying to use does not contain necessary functions for the linked list.
Its only a node in a linked list.
Below is an implementation of Linked List in Java you can use:

```
class Node {
    public int data;
    public Node next;
 
    public void displayNodeData() {
        System.out.println("{ " + data + " } ");
    }
}
 
public class SinglyLinkedList {
    private Node head;
 
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return (head == null);
    }
 
    // used to insert a node at the start of linked list
    public void insertFirst(int data) {
        Node newNode = new Node();
        newNode.data = data;
        newNode.next = head;
        head = newNode;
    }
 
    // used to delete node from start of linked list
    public Node deleteFirst() {
        Node temp = head;
        head = head.next;
        return temp;
    }
 
    // Use to delete node after particular node
    public void deleteAfter(Node after) {
        Node temp = head;
        while (temp.next != null && temp.data != after.data) {
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        if (temp.next != null)
            temp.next = temp.next.next;
    }
 
    // used to insert a node at the start of linked list
    public void insertLast(int data) {
        Node current = head;
        while (current.next != null) {
            current = current.next; // we'll loop until current.next is null
        }
        Node newNode = new Node();
        newNode.data = data;
        current.next = newNode;
    }
 
    // For printing Linked List
    public void printLinkedList() {
        System.out.println("Printing LinkedList (head --> last) ");
        Node current = head;
        while (current != null) {
            current.displayNodeData();
            current = current.next;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

However, i would prefer you use
[this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) when you are using linked list in an application.